# Is it possibe to pass options to a tcolorboxenvironment?

Tags: tcolorbox, theorems, thmtools

In the following MWE, I'm defining a theorem environment `theorem` via the `thmtools` package, and I'm embedding that environment in a tcolorbox, specifying a yellow background.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[
  style=theorem,
  name=Theorem,
]{theorem}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{colback=yellow}

\begin{document}

% \begin{theorem}[name={foo}, tcolorbox={colframe=red}] <-- maybe like this?
% \begin{theorem}[name={foo}]{colframe=red} <-- or like this?
\begin{theorem}[name={foo}]
  This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to then pass some `tcolorbox` options to that environment (`colframe=red` in the MWE) if they weren't already included in the second argument of `\tcolorboxenvironment`?

I know `tcolorbox` has a theorem library but I'd like to use two separate tools for two independent jobs (declaring theorems and boxing them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but in an indirect way.

Instead of defining `theorem` and `\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{colback=yellow}` I define `innertheorem` and do

```
\tcolorboxenvironment{innertheorem}{noibeoptions}
```

where `noibeoptions` will be a locally defined style. The optional argument to `theorem` will parse the options (I do it with `expl3`, but it could be done with Ti*k*Z parsing) and use `name` for the usual optional argument to theorems and any other key will be passed to `\tcbset` for defining the local style.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[
  style=theorem,
  name=Theorem,
]{innertheorem}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcolorboxenvironment{innertheorem}{colback=yellow,noibeoptions}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{theorem}{O{}}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { noibe/theorem } { #1 }
  \__noibe_tcbset:V \l__noibe_theorem_options_clist
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__noibe_theorem_name_tl
   { \begin{innertheorem} } { \begin{innertheorem}[\l__noibe_theorem_name_tl] }
 }
 {
  \end{innertheorem}
 }
\keys_define:nn { noibe/theorem }
 {
  name .tl_set:N = \l__noibe_theorem_name_tl,
  unknown .code:n = \clist_put_right:Nx \l__noibe_theorem_options_clist { \l_keys_key_str = #1 },
 }
\clist_new:N \l__noibe_theorem_options_clist
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__noibe_tcbset:n
 {
  \tcbset{noibeoptions/.style={#1}}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__noibe_tcbset:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[name={foo},colframe=red]
  This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[name={foo},colback=red]
  This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I guess this could be abstracted in order to avoid defining a new environment in the same way for each theorem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm working on your code right now. Is there a benefit to setting `\tcbset{<options>}` before every `innertheorem` instead of embedding `innertheorem` in a `\begin{tcolorbox}[<options] ... \end{tcolorbox}`?

Comment: @noibe I wanted to use the same method as `tcolorbox` for injecting the code. Maybe the final result is the same.

Comment: How should I change it so that in`theorem` I have a single key, `tcolorbox`, whose value is passed to `\tcbset`, while all the others (`name`, `label`, etc..) are passed to `innertheorem`?

Comment: @noibe Do you need a `label` key? `\begin{theorem}[<options>]\label{<label>}` is much cleaner. What are the other keys you have in mind?

Comment: What I had in mind was instead of explicitely defining and parsing the `thmtools` keys (`label` is just an example of such a key), I'd define a single additional key, `tcolorbox`, whose value is passed to `tcbset`, while all the others are passed to `innertheorem`.

Comment: @noibe Since I just see a need to pass the usual optional argument to theorem, I don't think this is really useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this can't reasonably be done with `\tcolorboxenvironment`, because if it allowed something like this, that could potentially break the syntax of the wrapped environment. `\tcolorboxenvironment` is very generic; it doesn't assume that the wrapped environment accepts an optional argument, nor that this optional argument uses “key=value syntax,” etc.

However, it is possible to define your own environment that wraps `theorem` and accepts an *additional* optional argument specifying keys to pass to the `tcolorbox`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[
  style=theorem,
  name=Theorem,
]{theorem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment { mytheorem } { !O{} !O{} }
  {
    \tcolorbox [colback=yellow, #2]
    % The 'theorem' env from thmtools doesn't like blank optional args
    \tl_if_blank:nTF {#1}
      { \begin{theorem} }
      { \begin{theorem}[#1] }
  }
  {
    \end{theorem}
    \endtcolorbox
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheorem}[name=foo]
  This is a theorem.
\end{mytheorem}

\begin{mytheorem}[name=bar][colframe=red]
  This is another theorem.
\end{mytheorem}

\begin{mytheorem}[][colback=blue!20]
  This is a third theorem.
\end{mytheorem}

\begin{mytheorem}
  This is a fourth theorem.
\end{mytheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]